# Getting a weird error when working with Laravel 4 and the php league OAuth2

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth2client

I'm trying to get a Social login with Facebook in place using Laravel and The league OAuth2 client but I'm getting this error:

```
Required option not passed: access_token Array ( [{"error":{"message":"Error_validating_client_secret_","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}] => )
```

I've followed the instructionns in the package github page, but I can't get it to work.

My controller action code:

```
 $facebook = $this->socialRepository->facebookLogin();
    $code = \Input::get("code");

    if(!isset($code)) {
        $authURL = $facebook->getAuthorizationUrl();
        return \Redirect::away($authURL);
    } else {
        $token = $facebook->getAccessToken('authorization_code', ['code' => $code]);
        try {
            $userDetails = $facebook->getUserDetails($token);
            dd($userDetails);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {}
    }
```

And the repository code:

```
public function facebookLogin()
{
    return new Facebook(
        [
            'clientId'      => $this->config->get("social.facebook.clientID"),
            'clientSecret'  => $this->config->get("social.facebook.clientSercret"),
            'redirectUri'   => $this->config->get("social.facebook.redirectUri"),
            'scopes'        => $this->config->get("social.facebook.scopes"),
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normally happens when the redirect URL, app ID or secret are incorrect.
For example,

```
'clientSecret'  => $this->config->get("social.facebook.clientSercret"),
```

Are you you meant `social.facebook.clientSercret` and not `social.facebook.clientSecret` (no extra `r`)

Comment: omg man, i'm so tired i didn't notice thanks a lot, eagle eye :D